# Execute code when two previous events have been processed (Apache Kafka)

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I´m new in Apache Kafka and Spring Boot. I´m trying to create a Spring Boot listener that generates a new event only when two specific messages (sent through Apache Kafka) have been received (for a determined resource).

The obvious solution is to use the database to change the status of the resource when the first event comes, and execute the code when the second event comes (if the customer is in the correct status in database). In this case, I'm worried if both events arrive at the same time.

Is there a way to aggregate both messages in Spring Boot/Apache Kafka instead do this manually?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you guaranteeing that those messages end up in the same partition, thus read by the same consumer thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with **kafka streams**. Example topology:

1. **input stream** (key/value from input topic A)
2. **filter** (filter by event type for example)
3. **groupBy** (group events by key or some field)
4. **aggregate** (aggregate events into new data structure)
5. **filter** (verify if aggregate its complete)
6. **map** (generate new output event with aggregate values)
7. **output stream** (key/value to topic B)

   Check details in official doc: https://kafka.apache.org/24/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#creating-source-streams-from-kafka

Comment: Thanks! It is what I needed. It is a little complex with custom objects but I´m progressing.